I am trying to build a transformer for multi class classification. But it gives the mismatch error
can anyone help me with the architecture, and highlight probably issues due to which the mismatch is occurring ( Incompatible shapes: [1,2048] vs. [1,256]. When the Transformer is build it also throws error, the params # is unbuilt and output layer remain a ?.
import tensorflow as tffrom tensorflow.keras.layers 
import Dense, LayerNormalization, Dropout, Input from tensorflow.keras.models 
import Modelfrom tensorflow.keras.optimizers 
import Adam

class MultiHeadSelfAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, num_heads=8):
        super(MultiHeadSelfAttention, self).__init__()
        self.embed_dim = embed_dim
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.projection_dim = embed_dim // num_heads
        self.query_dense = Dense(embed_dim)
        self.key_dense = Dense(embed_dim)
        self.value_dense = Dense(embed_dim)
        self.combine_heads = Dense(embed_dim)

    def attention(self, query, key, value):
        score = tf.matmul(query, key, transpose_b=True)
        dim_key = tf.cast(tf.shape(key)[-1], tf.float32)
        scaled_score = score / tf.math.sqrt(dim_key)
        weights = tf.nn.softmax(scaled_score, axis=-1)
        output = tf.matmul(weights, value)
        return output, weights

    def split_heads(self, inputs, batch_size):
        inputs = tf.reshape(inputs, (batch_size, -1, self.num_heads, self.projection_dim))
        return tf.transpose(inputs, perm=[0, 2, 1, 3])

    def call(self, inputs):
        batch_size = tf.shape(inputs)[0]
        query = self.query_dense(inputs)
        key = self.key_dense(inputs)
        value = self.value_dense(inputs)
        query = self.split_heads(query, batch_size)
        key = self.split_heads(key, batch_size)
        value = self.split_heads(value, batch_size)
        attention, weights = self.attention(query, key, value)
        attention = tf.transpose(attention, perm=[0, 2, 1, 3])
        concat_attention = tf.reshape(attention, (batch_size, -1, self.embed_dim))
        output = self.combine_heads(concat_attention)
        return output

class TransformerBlock(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim, rate=0.001):
        super(TransformerBlock, self).__init__()
        self.att = MultiHeadSelfAttention(embed_dim, num_heads)
        self.ffn = tf.keras.Sequential(
            [Dense(ff_dim, activation="relu"), Dense(embed_dim)]
        )
        self.layernorm1 = LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.layernorm2 = LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.dropout1 = Dropout(rate)
        self.dropout2 = Dropout(rate)

    def call(self, inputs, training):
        attn_output = self.att(inputs)
        attn_output = self.dropout1(attn_output, training=training)
        out1 = self.layernorm1(inputs + attn_output)
        ffn_output = self.ffn(out1)
        ffn_output = self.dropout2(ffn_output, training=training)
        return self.layernorm2(out1 + ffn_output)

class TransformerModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, num_layers, embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim, input_shape, rate=0.001, 
    num_classes=8):
        super(TransformerModel, self).__init__()
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.embedding = Dense(embed_dim)
        self.transformer_blocks = [
            TransformerBlock(embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim, rate)
            for _ in range(num_layers)
        ]
        self.global_average_pooling = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()
        self.dense = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')

    def build(self, input_shape):
        """Explicitly builds the model."""
        # You might not need to do anything specific here if your layers 
        # are already being initialized in __init__
    
        # Call super's build to mark the layer as built
        super(TransformerModel, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs, training):
        x = self.embedding(inputs)
        for i in range(self.num_layers):
            x = self.transformer_blocks[i](x, training=training)
        x = self.global_average_pooling(x)
        x = self.dense(x)
        return x

# Define number of classes and input dimension
num_classes = 8 
input_dim = 46  # Should match your `X_train` input feature size

# Instantiate and compile the Transformer model
transformer_model = TransformerModel(num_layers=6, embed_dim=256, num_heads=4, ff_dim=128, 

input_shape=(None, input_dim), num_classes=num_classes)

transformer_model.compile(
    optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',  # For multi-class classification
    metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall')]
)

# Build the model with a sample input shape
transformer_model.build(input_shape=(None, input_dim))

# Display model summary
transformer_model.summary()

# Train the Transformer model
import numpy as np
y_train_int = y_train_int.reshape(-1)
transformer_model.fit(X_train, y_train_int, epochs=50, batch_size=256, validation_split=0.2)

#Plotting Transformer Loss and Accuracy
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.plot(transformer_model.history['loss'], label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(transformer_model.history['val_loss'], label='Validation Loss')
plt.plot(transformer_model.history['accuracy'], label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(transformer_model.history['val_accuracy'], label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.title('Transformer Training and Validation Loss & Accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

#Plotting Recall for each class
plt.plot(transformer_model.history['recall'], label='Recall') 
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Recall')
plt.title('Transformer Recall for Each Class')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

I have tired to check for dimension of X_train and y_train and this is the output.
Unique values in y_train: [0.         0.14285715 0.2857143  0.42857143 0.5714286  0.71428573
 0.85714287 1.        ]
Counts of each unique value: [ 21822 676023 160657  52113   9760   7129    457    249]
Minimum value in y_train: 0.0
Maximum value in y_train: 1.0
X_train shape: (928210, 46)
Actual input_dim: 46
y_train_int shape: (928210, 1)
Label range: 0 to 7

